# Is the video 'Krieg: A Meat Bicycle Built For Two' an official part of the Borderlands Lore/Continuity?

Tags: borderlands-2

My brother and I got bored and while searching on YouTube we found a short film entitled *Krieg: A Meat Bicycle Built for Two*:

It shows Krieg murdering someone and later encountering and befriending Maya.

As a fan of the Borderlands series, I was curious: is this video part of the continuity or simply a fan-made video? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a video not in-game.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because it's about a specific video about a specific character that is specific to video games. As the help center points out, questions about "Plot and characters in games" are on-topic. It already has a decent answer, but y'know, "principle of the thing".

Answer (score 6):

That is an official video made by Gearbox as seen in the description on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6chxuovrbCI) and the [Borderlands Wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/File:Krieg_A_Meat_Bicycle_Built_for_Two-2#Description):

> What goes on inside the mind of Krieg the Psycho? Why did he become a Vault Hunter in the first place? Do his pecs, in fact, have pecs? Find out the answers to all these questions in this **original Gearbox short film**.